# How to make a slide show with sound with next and previous buttons control

Tags: java, android

I want to make a slideshow of numbers starting from 0 to 9 in pictures. When i click next button , show the picture of 1 and play sound as 'one' and so on.I want previous button to properly work.. like when I click previous button then go to previous pic and play sound which is related to that pic.

```
public class Numbers extends Activity {
int i = 1;
private ImageView iv;
Button next;
Button previous;
MediaPlayer ourSong;
private int currentImage = 0;
public int currentAudio = 0;



int[] images = { R.drawable.p1, R.drawable.p2, R.drawable.p3,
    R.drawable.p4, R.drawable.p5, R.drawable.p6, R.drawable.p7,
    R.drawable.p8, R.drawable.p9, R.drawable.p10};
int[] audios = { R.raw.a1, R.raw.a2, R.raw.a3, R.raw.a4, R.raw.a5,
    R.raw.a6, R.raw.a7, R.raw.a8, R.raw.a9, R.raw.a10};
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.nextpre);

iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivn);
next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonn);
previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonp);
// Just set one Click listener for the image

next.setOnClickListener(iButtonChangeImageListener);
previous.setOnClickListener(gButtonChangeImageListener);

}
View.OnClickListener iButtonChangeImageListener = new View.OnClickListener()      {

public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        // Increase Counter to move to next Image
        currentImage++;

        currentImage = currentImage % images.length;

        iv.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);



        ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this,
                audios[currentAudio+1]);

        ourSong.start();
        currentAudio++;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}

};

View.OnClickListener gButtonChangeImageListener = new View.OnClickListener()    {

public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        // Decrease Counter to move to previous Image
        currentImage--;

        currentImage = (currentImage + images.length) % images.length;

        iv.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);

        MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this, audios[currentAudio]);
        ourSong.start();
        currentAudio--;

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
};

protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPause();
ourSong.release();
finish();
   }

     @Override
 protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this,
        audios[0]);

ourSong.start();


}
}
```

Comment: You've posted requirements and quite a bit of unexplained code but have asked no question. Please fix this so that we can know how to help you. What's wrong with your code? What specifically confuses you? Consider going through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how you can improve this question and your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm if you're trying to make a slide show, you might want to look into view pagers they look like this:

[image]

View pagers are highly customizable, You can add buttons and images and pretty much almost anything a fragment can hold on each screen. Not sure what your skill level is but ill tell you whats involved in getting this to work.

1. Create a layout with a view pager in it.
2. Create a class that extends the FragmentPagerAdapter
3. Override getItem() method in the adapter (this is where you define your different "screens"
4. Create a class that extends fragment for each screen you want to show your users.

Doing it this way in order to switch screens u just have to call setCurrentItem to change pages (when user clicks next or prev)

--edit--

Apparently theres also a something called an ImageSwitcher.
They look like this:
[image]

This is actually better for your case since you only want images. It looks a lot easier to implement than a view pager. This describes how to implement it: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_imageswitcher.htm